# Subtle protocol difference

Tags: swift, protocols

Lets say we define a protocol

```
public protocol ScreenFlags {
    var cornerRadius: CGFloat { get }
}
```

now I can implement it for example:

```
struct ScreenFlagsImpl: ScreenFlags {
    var cornerRadius: CGFloat { return 0 }
}
```

or

```
struct ScreenFlagsImpl: ScreenFlags {
    let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0
}
```

I am curious about the subtle differences here and possible dangers. Which of the implementations produces smaller/cleaner code in case the cornerRadius never changes and is there a way to enforce that cornerRadius is a constant not a variable

Comment: Cleaner code? If the property never changes then use `let`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "produces smaller/cleaner code"? Do you mean generated asm/machine code?

Comment: I think OP was asking if there is a way to enforce a protocol's property to be only stored but not computed. Unfortunately I think the answer is no and this doesn't seem worth bothering.

Comment: Is it fair to close this question as opinion-based given that one of the answers (disclosure: mine) covers technical internals (to address subtle differences between the two approaches) and not opinions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this compiler explorer [link](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:swift,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:12,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:12,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:11,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:11),source:%27import+Foundation+%0A%0Apublic+protocol+ScreenFlags+%7B%0A++++var+cornerRadius:+CGFloat+%7B+get+%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Astruct+ScreenFlagsImplComputed:+ScreenFlags+%7B%0A++++var+cornerRadius:+CGFloat+%7B+return+0+%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Astruct+ScreenFlagsImplStored:+ScreenFlags+%7B%0A++++let+cornerRadius:+CGFloat+%3D+0%0A%7D%0A%0Alet+screenFlagsComputed+%3D+ScreenFlagsImplComputed()%0Alet+screenFlagsStored+%3D+ScreenFlagsImplStored()%0A%0Alet+cr+%3D+screenFlagsComputed.cornerRadius%0Aprint(cr)%0Alet+cr1+%3D+screenFlagsStored.cornerRadius%0Aprint(cr)%0Aprint(MemoryLayout%3CScreenFlagsImplComputed%3E.size)%0Aprint(MemoryLayout%3CScreenFlagsImplStored%3E.size)%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Swift+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:32.5628802748884,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:swift59,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:swift,libs:!(),options:%27-O+-Rpass%3D.*%27,overrides:!((name:stdver,value:gnu%2B%2B17)),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:6,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:6,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:5,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:5),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+swiftc+5.9+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:34.10378639177827,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%271%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:swift59,compilerName:%27%27,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:swift,libs:!(),options:%27%27,overrides:!((name:stdver,value:gnu%2B%2B17)),runtimeTools:!(),source:1,stdinPanelShown:%270%27,tree:0,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Executor+x86-64+swiftc+5.9+(Swift,+Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4). Right click > "reveal linked code" to inspect corresponding assembly.

## Subtle Differences

Renaming the implementations to reflect their underlying mechanisms.

```swift
struct ScreenFlagsImplComputed: ScreenFlags {
    var cornerRadius: CGFloat { return 0 }
}

struct ScreenFlagsImplStored: ScreenFlags {
    let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0
}
```

`ScreenFlagsImplComputed` uses a computed property, which compiles down to a function that returns zero.

[image]

With optimizations this will get inlined, const-folded and will compile down to one or two instructions. So, a simple assignment

```swift
let cr = screenFlagsComputed.cornerRadius
```

can compile down to a single instruction for a constant value like 0.

[image: Global let constant cr gets assigned the value 0]

The value zero is not stored in the struct instances as it is not a stored property.

```swift
print( MemoryLayout<ScreenFlagsImplComputed>.size ) // prints '0'
```

You get your protocol implementation basically for "free".

`ScreenFlagsImplStored` stores it explicitly, and arbitrary code cannot reason that it is going to be the constant zero. So, it will be read from the memory location where the struct is stored, which will usually be one extra instruction, the first is a load from the struct instance `screenFlagsImplStored`, the second is the assignment itself to the global variable.

```swift
print( MemoryLayout<ScreenFlagsImplStored>.size )  // prints e.g. `8`, machine dependent
```

[image]

## Dangers?

I do not see any memory unsafety, API misuse etc kind of dangers in either of the two approaches.

For most practical purposes the performance difference between the two should also be negligible, unless you are processing a lot of `ScreenFlagsImpl` objects, and even then measure first. I would personally go for the computed property implementation since it has less overhead overall. It is also much easier for the compiler to optimize especially when you can add `@inlinable` and friends for cross-module optimization. Whether it's significant will have to be determined by careful measurements using well-designed benchmarks, runtime profiles etc.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer! What do you think - if we have a hierarchy Module1Flags -> Screen1Flags/Screen2Flags/Screen3Flags... -> cornerRadius will the compiler again succeeds to make the protocol 'free' when using computed properties?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by this hierarchy? Are Screen1Flags etc concrete types that have different implementation of the ScreenFlags protocol?

Comment: If you want diagnostic information about optimization, compile with the flag `-Rpass-missed=specialize` like I did in the compiler explorer link in my answer. That'll tell you whether the compiler made this optimization or not. To make sure that the compiler is able to do this optimization from other modules, add `@inlinable` at the computed property definition.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 versions:

1.

```swift
struct ScreenFlagsImpl: ScreenFlags {
    var cornerRadius: CGFloat { return 0 }
}
```

2. 

```swift
struct ScreenFlagsImpl: ScreenFlags {
    let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0
}
```

If your `cornerRadius` is really a constant then version 2 (with `let` constant) is preferable.

On the other hand, if your corner radius is constant for all `ScreenFlags` then it is better to add default implementation of the protocol:

```swift
extension ScreenFlags {
    var cornerRadius: CGFloat { return 0 } // Or somethings else you need
}
```